# Reg:Secure soap using karate dsl

Tags: soap, karate

I need to test secure soap using karate framework. Does any one know if its possible using karate. how to send an encrypted soap file and then decrypt the message later

Comment: please read: https://stackoverflow.com/q/70594629/143475

Comment: Nope I want to encrypt the soap msg using a local key before sending it. Wanted to know hpw to do it using Karate dsl

Comment: I have nothing to add to my comment above.